# Index out of range in python and the Flask framework

Tags: python

for some reason, the python interpreter thinks that the index is out of range but it isn't!

```
list_of_venues = Venue.query.with_entities(Venue.id, Venue.city, Venue.state, Venue.name).all()
  data = []
  #{'city': list_of_venues[0].city, 'state': list_of_venues[0].state, 'venues':[]}
  counter = 0
  # print(len(list_of_venues))
  # print(data[counter]["city"])
  

  for venue in list_of_venues:
    print(counter)
    # print(data[counter]["city"])
    if counter == 0:
      city_dict={}
      city_dict["city"] = venue.city
      city_dict["state"] = venue.state
      city_dict["venues"] = []
      data.append(city_dict)
      city_dict = {}
    if counter > 0:
      if venue.city != data[counter]["city"]:
        city_dict={}
        city_dict["city"] = venue.city
        city_dict["state"] = venue.state
        city_dict["venues"] = []
        data.append(city_dict)
        city_dict = {}
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
    # if counter != (len(list_of_venues) - 1):
    #   counter = counter + 1

  print(data)

  data = list_of_venues
  


  return render_template('pages/venues.html', areas=data)
```

this is the line of the error :       `if venue.city != data[counter]["city"]:`

and this is the Error : IndexError: list index out of range

Thank you for your time guiding me!

Comment: You don't need to reset `city_dict = {}` at end of `if`, that will happen when you do `city_dict = {}` at beginning of '`if'. Also as previous comment indicated indexes are 0 based.

Answer (score 0):

In your code your `data` variable is an empty list of length 0, so when the loop goes to the second iteration and `counter` is now 1, it throws an error.

Move your assignment of data

```
data = list_of_venues
```

up to before the loop and it should work.

So if you have

```
list_of_venues = Venue.query.with_entities(Venue.id, Venue.city, Venue.state, Venue.name).all()
  data = []
  #{'city': list_of_venues[0].city, 'state': list_of_venues[0].state, 'venues':[]}
  counter = 0
  # print(len(list_of_venues))
  # print(data[counter]["city"])
  data = list_of_venues
  for venue in list_of_venues:
    print(counter)
    # print(data[counter]["city"])
    if counter == 0:
      city_dict={}
      city_dict["city"] = venue.city
      city_dict["state"] = venue.state
      city_dict["venues"] = []
      data.append(city_dict)
      city_dict = {}
    if counter > 0:
      if venue.city != data[counter]["city"]:
        city_dict={}
        city_dict["city"] = venue.city
        city_dict["state"] = venue.state
        city_dict["venues"] = []
        data.append(city_dict)
        city_dict = {}
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
    # if counter != (len(list_of_venues) - 1):
    #   counter = counter + 1
  print(data)
  return render_template('pages/venues.html', areas=data)
```

It should work.